# Problem to insert with psycopg2 with python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to insert some rows, but this problema occurs:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

sql code:
`f"""insert into {table} ({insert}) VALUES ({formating}) ON CONFLICT ({', '.join(key)}) DO UPDATE SET ({insert}) = ({excluded})"""`

sql translate:
`insert into public.atend (cd_atendimento, cd_ori_ate, cd_paciente, op_type) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) ON CONFLICT (cd_atendimento) DO UPDATE SET (cd_atendimento, cd_ori_ate, cd_paciente, op_type) = (EXCLUDED.cd_atendimento, EXCLUDED.cd_ori_ate, EXCLUDED.cd_paciente, EXCLUDED.op_type)`

Comment: The issue is that you specified 4 parameter substitutions, but you didn't supply 4 elements in the `execute` call.  Since you didn't show us ANY of your Python code, we can't advise you on that.

Comment: An additional problem is you did not read this [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) and this [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) and have opened yourself to SQL injection.